# Can I copy the LFS settings in .gitattribute to another repository

Tags: git, git-lfs

I'd like to filter the same file types on several (existing) repositories. Of course I could manually add the filters one by one to each repository, or write a bash script. But it would be much easier to just copy the `.gitattributes` into each repository. However I'm not sure if this is safe, since I don't know if there is something that git sets in the `.git` of the repo as well.

Comment: Git generally ignores anything in a `.gitattributes` file that doesn't mean anything to Git. This has its good aspects (enables this kind of git-lfs stuff) and its bad aspects (a simple typo makes things fail without any error messages).

Answer (score 1):

Of course I found my answer seconds after posting the question. Yea it's fine. This is from the git-lfs documentation.

> In each Git repository where you want to use Git LFS, select the file
> types you'd like Git LFS to manage (or directly edit your
> .gitattributes). You can configure additional file extensions at
> anytime.